# How to randomly get a string from a collection but prefer strings at the beginning of the collection

Tags: c#, random

If I have a list that contains the following strings:

```
  "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"
```

What is the best way to get a random string but be weighted in a way that it will be more likely to get "a" rather than "n"?

Comment: Should be dup of [weighted random](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]weighted+random) questions.

Comment: How much more likely should "a" be compared to "n"? `return "a";` fulfils your requirement :P

Comment: Here's an answer that should suffice for you with modifications: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538795/3317555

Comment: `return a;` returns a random string with a returning more likely than n. Relies on cosmic radiation to produce non-a results.

Comment: @Aron :) [XKCD:Random Number](http://3d.xkcd.com/221/) is good too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select two random numbers and pick the lower one.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomItem = list[Math.Min(rnd.Next(list.Count+1), rnd.Next(list.Count+1))];
```

And I'd urge you to determine for yourself the resulting relative probabilities of each item.

If you come up with a more rigorous definition of 'best' then this answer probably won't suit it.

Comment: This seems like tournament selection in evolutionary algorithms. Unfortunately, the question does not suggest what the right tournament size should be.. Is that 2, 5, 100, or more?

Comment: Thanks for the solution and sorry about the lack of clarity - it was 4am

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to get a random string but be weighted in a way that it will be more likely to get "a" rather than "n"?

You should clarify the distribution you are willing to get. "More likely" is not clear enough.

By example, you might use:

```
for i in 1..size(array) do
  if random(0.0,1.0) < k then
    return array[i]
end for
return array[i]
```

But for different values of `k`, you'll get much different behavior.

For `k=1.0`, you'll always get the first element. For `k=1/size(array)`, you'll get a random element.